# Kendo UI Grid Item Create Function Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I made a kendo grid with a toolbar to create new records, but when the update button is pressed the create function in the data source I expect to be called isn't being called. I took this code from another page in the code where it works perfectly fine and I scanned both page to make sure I'm not missing any sort of library and on top of that the debugger isn't outputting anthing either.

```
var RegionalMappingDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: function(options) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: siteRoot + '/Admin/RegionMapping/GetRegionMappings',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(result) {
                            options.success(result);
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            options.error(result);
                        }
                    });
                },
                create: function () { // This is the method I expected to be called
                    console.log("it hits create");
                },
                save: function () { // Checked to make sure this method isn't called
                    console.log("it hits save");
                }
            }
        });

$("#Regionmappinggrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: RegionalMappingDataSource,
    groupable: false,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    editable: "inline",
    toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Update Other Region Name" }], // where I tried to bind to method 
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Country Name",
            field: "CountryCode",
            editor: function(container, options) {
                var input = $('<input required id="mapping" name="' + options.field + '"/>');
                input.appendTo(container);
                input.kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: true,
                    optionLabel: 'Please Select Country....',
                    dataTextField: "Value",
                    dataValueField: "Key",
                    dataSource: getCountryName,
                    value: options.model.Key,
                    text: options.model.Value
                }).appendTo(container);
            }

        },
        {
            title: "Region Name",
            field: "RegionName",
            editor: function(container, options) {
                var input = $('<input required id="mapping1" name="' + options.field + '"/>');
                input.appendTo(container);
                input.kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    optionLabel: 'Please Select Region....',
                    dataTextField: "Value",
                    dataValueField: "Key",
                    dataSource: getRegionName,
                    value: options.model.Key,
                    text: options.model.Value
                }).appendTo(container);
            }

        },
        {
            title: "Region ID",
            field: "RegionId",
            hidden: true
        },
        {
            title: "Other Name",
            field: "Name"
        },
        {
            title: "Updated On",
            field: "UpdatedDate",
            format: "{0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}",
            editable: function() { return false; }
        },
        {
            command: ["edit", "destroy"]
        }
    ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Create function of the DataSource is called when the user presses the "Update" button that is rendered on the row of the new item. Can you confirm that upon pressing the "Update" button, the function is executed as expected?

As per automatically calling the Create function after the "Add new item" button is clicked, you should set the AutoSync property of the DataSource to "true". This would cause it to update automatically right after every change.

[https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/autosync][AutoSync property]

﻿

Comment: Yeah that's the exact issue when the Update button is pressed, the create function in the datasource isn't being called

Comment: Can you try it in the following example https://dojo.telerik.com/ameMiliM? Also, it would be helpful if you could share the exact setup of your grid.